# Best way to handle Hibernate Sessions in a layered Spring MVC Web application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

If we have a web application which has

- heavy UI (Spring MVC + JQuery with JSON)
- Hibernate with JPA annotations being the domain model
- extend Spring-provided DAO to code DAO layer
- JBOSS being the app server with Oracle as backend
- Datasource (JNDI) based connection pooling (Not an XA rather Local data source)
- also has access to multiple data sources (dealing with multiple DB)

Behaviorally, lot of Data retrieval (70%) and update of data being 30%
What would be the best practices for the following to effectively consume DB connections   and also see to that there is no much leakage at connection usage?

1. would it be better to opt for Hibernate template based DAOs?
2. What kind of transaction manager would be suggest-able and should we go for AOP-based transaction managementWhere
3. where to instantiate session and and where to close the sessions to effectively consume connections from connection pooling.
4. It is true that we need to handle transactions from Service layer but what happens to sessions would they be waiting for longer time (we are not using any opensessioninviewFilter)
5. which layer is better to handle the checked exceptions (business exceptions) and runtime exceptions.

Sorry for this being bit lengthier question, however I see that this is being a common query and I tried consolidating it. Appreciate your patience and guidance. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if we planned to use Database partitioning( Table Range/Hash partition) at the Backend. Does Hibernate (or Shards? Not yet into production!)  support that?

Answer (score 17):

This sounds like a pretty typical Spring/Hibernate application, so I would recommend following current best practices, which I recently outlined in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709750/proper-usage-of-spring-mvc-3-with-hibernate-spring-orm/6710885#6710885). Specifically:

1. Do *not* extend Spring DAO support classes or use HibernateTemplate. Use the [@Repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) annotation combined with component scanning, and [directly inject the SessionFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-exception-translation) into your DAO.
2. Use Spring's [HibernateTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html), and definitely use [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) via [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) as your default approach.
3. Let [Spring manage that](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-resource-synchronization-high). It will open sessions just in time for transactions by default, but prefer the [open session in view pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) enabled by Spring's [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html).
4. See #3.
5. Always handle exceptions where they should be handled--in other words, this is a design decision. Note, however, that the Spring transaction framework by default [rolls back on unchecked exceptions](http://transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings), but not checked, to match the behavior of the EJB spec. Make sure to set the proper rollback rules (see previous link) anywhere you use checked exceptions.

Additionally, use a connection pool, obviously. [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) is a great choice. "Not much leakage in connection usage" isn't enough. You have to have zero connection leakage. Depending on Spring to manage your resources will help ensure this. As for any other performance issues, don't try to optimize prematurely. Wait until you see where your problem areas are, and then figure out the best way to solve each one individually. Since your bottlenecks will most likely be database-related, check out [the performance chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/performance.html) of the Hibernate reference to get an idea what you're up against. It covers the important concepts of caching and fetching strategies.

Comment: I'd prefer EntityManager to SessionFactory though

Comment: @Bozho: Doesn't really matter which you use, though I've never heard a compelling reason to use EntityManager.

Comment: It's standard. If at some point hibernate fails you, you can just straight to EclipseLink almost without effort

Comment: @Bozho: At this point, hibernate is so much more mature and established than the standard--not to mention the standard was essentially built off of hibernate--that I'm comfortable sticking with direct hibernate interaction in order to avoid the extra complexity that JPA seems to bring with it. (<-- Mostly uninformed opinion formed from looking over JPA docs)

Comment: I've been using ir with jpa for the past 2 years and it was perfectly fine. Esp. with jpa2

Comment: @Ryan - 1)I am just wondering if we have some limitations in terms of connection consumption with OpenSessioninViewFilter.http://sysin.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/limitations-of-opensessioninviewfilter/ and also  DBCP http://wiki.apache.org/commons/DBCP/Hibernate

Comment: 1: Connection consumption is very unlikely to be a problem. Do you have any reason to think that it would be? Optimize when you have a problem, not before. 2: That DBCP page is talking about a feature of Hibernate 2, which is ancient history. Don't use that DBCP. Use [real DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

Comment: Hi, I saw this in OpenSessionInViewFilter, `A single session per request allows for most efficient first-level caching, but can cause side effects, for example on saveOrUpdate or when continuing after a rolled-back transaction.`, as for side effects I do not understand, what are the problems?

Answer (score 3):

- Use JPA `EntityManager` directly in your DAOs. Be sure not to mark it as Extended
- Prefer `<tx:annotation-driven />` and `@Transactional` - only on the service layer
- The transaction manager also opens and closes sessions (if one doesn't exist already in the thread). Here it is good to know that sessions are session-per-request. Each request(=thread) has a separate session instance. But a database connection is created only if one is needed, so even if there is a transaction manager around all methods, needless connections won't be opened.
- read-only transactions - use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` in cases when there is only data retrieval
- caching - utilize hibernate 2nd level cache to put entities in memory (instead of fetching them from the database each time)
- avoid `OpenSessionInView` and lazy collections. This is subjective, but in my opinion all objects that leave the service layer must be initialized. For small collections (for ex. list of roles) you can have eager collections. For bigger collections use HQL queries.

Comment: I agree that it is standard. Would you please differentiate if we have any other advantages in terms of performance or resource utilisation with EntityManager. Also if we want to support DB table Horizontal partitioning, what would be the recommended technology?

Comment: same. If you really end up needing the raw hibernate session or even connection, you can get it by `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`